# difference between changing varchar(lower value) datatype to varchar(higher value) and vice versa

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, mysql-5.7, alter

I am using MySQL 5.7.17

When I changed the data type of a large test table from varchar(45) to varchar(50), it took only less than a second to complete.

I couldn't find a good document explaining why this happened so fast. Please help.

(We are going to change the datatype from varchar(45) to varchar(50) on our huge production table, and it will be helpful for us to calculate the downtime needed for this.)

Comment: *I couldn't find a good document explaining why this happened so fast. Please help.* Read about [InnoDB online DDL operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table has a "definition" (the `CREATE TABLE...`) and it has the data and the indexes.

If an `ALTER` can be performed without changing the way the data is stored, then it can (in most cases, and in recent versions), do it by changing the definition without touching the actual data.

So, let's look at how a `VARCHAR(N)` column is stored:

For short *definitions* (that is, for small N):

```
* 1-byte length field
* a variable number of bytes to hold the actual _characters_
```

For bigger columns (N=256 certainly qualifies):

```
* 2-byte length field
* a variable number of bytes to hold the actual characters
```

So, switching from N=40 to N=50 would not need to touch the data, but N=45 to N=266 would, I think, require rewriting all the data.

(I am being a bit vague on N because a "character" can take more than one "byte", depending on the `COLLATION`.)

Perhaps the slowest `ALTER` is if you change the `PRIMARY KEY`.  That requires reshuffling the data because it is ordered by the PK and requires rebuilding all the secondary indexes since they include a copy of the PK.

In the middle of the spectrum are some `INDEX` operations.  `DROP INDEX` is pretty cheap -- remove from the definition and then clean up the space consumed by it.  `ADD INDEX` is more costly because it needs to populate a new BTree to hold the index.  Meanwhile, the data and any other secondary indexes can remain untouched.  The code, however, is necessarily tricky -- what if rows are being modified while the index is being built.

Answer (score 0):

> This one should be faster, there's no truncation of values because you
> are increasing the length.
>
> But I suggest to make a copy of existing table, after changing the
> length, you can rename the tables. Renaming of tables should be
> faster.

Comment: This tells about nothing. Converting VARCHAR(45) to VARCHAR(256) does not perform truncation too but it will be slow due to INPLACE is not applicable for such change. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ac5e993900ac51176b3a403592ea98cd

Comment: @Akina, thanks for the comments, but I did not mention that "there will be truncation". I think you misunderstood my statement. Please read it carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Your 1st sentence tells that "This one should be faster (effect), there's no truncation of values because you are increasing the length (reason)." Logical invertion (truncation -> slower) changes nothing.

Comment: @Akina my first line is a declarative sentence, not imperative. I just emphasize that if changing length to lower value might truncate some data and it will become slower.